# Ordenar While por inserção no Banco de dados MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estou querendo que meu while em vez de Criar o bloco "element-item" para baixo, crie o bloco para cima, ou seja **ele vai ordenando do mais novo para o mais velho e não do mais velho para o mais novo**

EXEMPLO:
O que ele ta fazendo:

```
BLOCO ID1 - BLOCO ID2 - BLOCO ID3
```

o que eu quero:

```
BLOCO ID3 - BLOCO ID2 - BLOCO ID1
```

Meu código:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$banco      = 'apixel_galeria';
$usuario  = 'root';
$senha    = '';
$link     = @mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db          = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
if(!$link)
{
    echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $sql["id"];
$nome = $sql["nome"];
$tipo = $sql["tipo"];
$desc = $sql["desc"];
$menu = $sql["menu"];
$imageM = $sql["imageM"];
$imageF = $sql["imageF"];
    ?>
          <div class="element-item <?php echo "$menu";?>" data-category="transition">
       <a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                                <img src="<?php echo "$imageM"?>" alt="project 2">
             <div class="mask">    <div class="conteudo_mask" style="
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    /* float: left; */
    ">                   <h1><?php echo "$nome"?></h1>                   <div id="lin" style="
    width: 200px;
"></div>                   <h2><?php echo "$tipo"?></h2>                                                    </div><h3 style="
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
">VEJA <br><img src="images/mais.png" alt="mais" style="width: 20px;height: 19px;margin-bottom: -1px;margin-top: 3px;"></h3></div>
                                </a>
  </div>

        <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC` tentou isso?

Comment: onde coloco isso amigo?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: vlw amigo deu certo, tinha esquecido disso :)

Comment: Que bom, pode marcar resposta do Renato Tavares como aceita :)

Comment: :) pronto obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$banco      = 'apixel_galeria';
$usuario  = 'root';
$senha    = '';
$link     = @mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha);
$db          = mysql_select_db($banco,$link);
if(!$link)
{
    echo "erro ao conectar ao banco de dados!";exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$id = $sql["id"];
$nome = $sql["nome"];
$tipo = $sql["tipo"];
$desc = $sql["desc"];
$menu = $sql["menu"];
$imageM = $sql["imageM"];
$imageF = $sql["imageF"];
    ?>
          <div class="element-item <?php echo "$menu";?>" data-category="transition">
       <a href="#portfolioModal54" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                                <img src="<?php echo "$imageM"?>" alt="project 2">
             <div class="mask">    <div class="conteudo_mask" style="
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    /* float: left; */
    ">                   <h1><?php echo "$nome"?></h1>                   <div id="lin" style="
    width: 200px;
"></div>                   <h2><?php echo "$tipo"?></h2>                                                    </div><h3 style="
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
">VEJA <br><img src="images/mais.png" alt="mais" style="width: 20px;height: 19px;margin-bottom: -1px;margin-top: 3px;"></h3></div>
                                </a>
  </div>

        <?php
}
?>
```

Considerações:

- Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)
- Nunca misture HTML e PHP
- Você pode dar echo assim `<?= $somevar ?>`

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda :)